# How to redirect all subpages using htaccess and exclude specific URLs?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect using htaccess, but I do not know much about htaccess and redirection. What I want to do is:

redirect access to all subpages and directories e.g.

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php
http://mydomain.com/directory/
http://mydomain.com/new/directory/
```

to a specific URL on my domain say:

```
http://mydomain.com/one
```

I try to do it with

```
redirect /index.php http://mydomain.com/demo/
```

But my question is how to EXCLUDE specific URLs and directories from this redirection? How can I make rule to exclude specific pages from being redirected?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your "tool of choice" should be **RewriteCond**

The `RewriteCond` directive can be used to filter more than just a URL, and each condition only applies to the next `RewriteRule` directive - you can "stack" `RewriteCond` directives, however.

Example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/non/redirect/url.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/another/non/redirect/url.php$
RewriteRule ^$ http://mydomain.com/one
```

However, this can be simplified a litte:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/path/to/non/redirect/url.php|/path/to/another/non/redirect/url.php)$
RewriteRule /index.php http://mydomain.com/one
```

[Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)